# What are these purple pickups?

Tags: doom-eternal

There's a lot of loot (and blood) in this game.  I've figured out what most of the ammo and other pickups are, but what are these purple things?

[image: Purple pickup]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Plasma cores, ammo for the Plasma Rifle and Ballista